# Drag and drop to attachments feature only working intermittently in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-registry

I've been trying to troubleshoot a problem with my Outlook 2010 install where the ability to drag and drop an attachment into a new email will stop working from time to time. It seems to be fairly moonphase-y in that I can't seem to find a correlation in what causes it to stop working.

Some searching online lead me to try running this command through the windows run dialogue: Regsvr32 ole32.dll, which apparently re-registers that particular dll as a command component in the registry. It didn't work, but I was curious as to why it was a suggested fix, and if there was something similar to try that would work, or another known solution.

Comment: When it happens (goes wrong) is there anything in event viewer - is it for certain files or all files. Is your machine doing a back up at the time or running programs which could lock your outlook folders/temporary folders (or a virus scan)

Answer (score 0):

I have not experienced that issue, but repairing your Office suite may resolve the issue.

1. Open up the Control Panel on your PC (and show All Control Panel items, if necessary) and click on Programs and Features
2. Find Office 2010 in the list and highlight it
3. Press the Change button Select Repair and press Continue and following the prompts